# System.Net.Http type mismatch at compile

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

Since updating a .Net Framework Web Api2 project to .Net Framework 4.7.1 and updating references to the now native `System.Net.Http` library, we now get the following error at compile time (not the typical runtime). Thus assembly binding redirects have no effect.

> The type 'HttpResponseMessage' exists in both
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  SkinOnline.Web  C:_dev\MapsOnline.Web\API\Controllers\Utilites\LongProcessController.cs

I've no idea where the older version is coming from - perhaps one of the project dependencies.

**Edit**
So after adding the dll from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.1

Once under references the path has changed to

> C:\VS2017\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net471\lib\System.Net.Http.dll

And that says the Version is `4.2.0.0`

Comment: have you looked at other layers in your project ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So in fact the new native file is version 4.2.0.0 (no idea what the folks were doing here given the latest version before this consolidation was 4.3.3).

Indeed we do require the binding redirect.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Without it I get weird runtime errors

> System.MissingMethodException Method not found:
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()'.

Comment: The binding redirect works both way and allows choosing which version of the assembly to use in the project. For now it seems the only way to fix the issue.

Comment: You may also need to remove the System.Net.Http reference from the project to get it to build. Many times installing a Nuget package will automatically add this reference but pointing to the wrong file.

Comment: Binding redirect in my web role project didn't solve this problem at all. Still trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are hitting is that even though the new System.Net.Http binary (4.2.0.0) is copied in the same folder of the app, the right binding redirects are not being generated automatically by the VS tooling. We recently fixed this with this pull request: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/25786

Once that fix is consumed by Visual Studio, the right binding redirect will be generated automatically for you and you won't see this issue anymore. This fix will be included in Visual Studio 15.6 Preview 3. For the time being, adding the binding redirect manually will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps with understanding the scope of the problem.